# Charles Proxy - View request as .. Image not working

Tags: charles-proxy

I am using Charles Proxy to review my app which sends some requests as images, the request has `Content-Type    image/jpeg` and if I save the request to my finder, image will be previewed correctly.

[image: Save request... option]

However this is pretty time consuming, I would like to see the preview directly on charles because I'm reviewing several dozens of images. The **View Request As ... Image** doesn't seem to change anything in the Overview/contents/summary etc tabs bellow.

Is there a way to preview images from Charles app?

[image: View Request As ... option]